# Error pointing Godaddy domain to VPS

Tags: godaddy, dns-zone, glue-record, soa-record

I just have bought a new domain on the provider Godaddy.

I'm trying to set up the glue records in order to point to my point to my server: 137.74.194.89

I think I've done everything ok in my server because it answer ok to my querys on localhost.

```
    [root@vps named]# dig somosiceberg.es. NS @127.0.0.1

    ; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-38.el7_3 <<>> somosiceberg.es. NS @127.0.0.1
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; Got answer:
    ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 15076
    ;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 3
    ;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

    ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
    ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
    ;; QUESTION SECTION:
    ;somosiceberg.es.       IN  NS

    ;; ANSWER SECTION:
    somosiceberg.es.    3600    IN  NS  ns1.somosiceberg.es.
    somosiceberg.es.    3600    IN  NS  ns2.somosiceberg.es.

    ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
    ns1.somosiceberg.es.    3600    IN  A   137.74.194.89
    ns2.somosiceberg.es.    3600    IN  A   137.74.194.89

    ;; Query time: 0 msec
    ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
    ;; WHEN: jue mar 09 23:42:41 CET 2017
    ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 112
```

If I do this same query in other pc the answer is different.

```
pc pc # dig somosiceberg.es. @a.nic.es

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.5-Ubuntu <<>> somosiceberg.es. @a.nic.es
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 28539
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;somosiceberg.es.       IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
somosiceberg.es.    86400   IN  NS  ns1.somosiceberg.es.
somosiceberg.es.    86400   IN  NS  ns2.somosiceberg.es.

;; Query time: 20 msec
;; SERVER: 194.69.254.1#53(194.69.254.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar 09 23:45:02 CET 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 80
```

As you can see the CA doesn't serve the ip of the subdomains so the domain can not be resolved.

The configuration I have on goodaddy panel is [Host domain configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WXHV.png) wich is the normal configuration for a glue record that the company support told me to do.

I think that the problem comes from Godaddy propagation but I have no idea how to prove this. I have talk so many times with their support team and they have no idea how to solve this.

The last they told me was

> We have added the glue records for NS1.SOMOSICEBERG.ES,
>   NS2.SOMOSICEBERG.ES. However we continue to see an error that no SOA
>   record exists.

Any help is wellcome. I'm completely stuck on this.

Greetings all.

Comment: Tip: add `+trace` to your dig queries to see the answers from each step in the path. Your domain does not have a SOA record (via `dig -t soa`), so you should add that to your zone file. That may or may not be related to your glue record problem, but getting the SOA record sorted first eliminates it as a possible source.

Comment: How long ago you did the DNS's change ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 I did it like 3 days ago.

Comment: @Animism I think I can't add SOA to my zone file because the querys are not reaching my server.

Answer (score 0):

A dig from multiple source list your nameserver as **fail**. (SERVFAIL)

If you goal is simply to serve the record you need, then use godaddy.com nameserver please, it will be a lot simpler.

Please fix your nameserver first if you dont want to use godaddy.con ns, as seen on;

[image]

Comment: I think this fail is because there is no ip for ns1 and ns2. I have my own dns server that is working properly in my other domains(not hosted on godaddy) with the same configuration so i would rather use my own. Again, as I say i think that error is a problem of connection because if you use my ip on the nameserver you will see that is working ok. Thanks.